# How to return different types from mapper method in Java?

Tags: java, generics, polymorphism

How can I return different types in one method and make set operations above them?
For example, I have a few similar classes: `AddDeveloperResponse, EditDeveloperResponse, DeleteDeleveloperResponse`

In general, I had 3 methods, where I return these different classes, but I think it can make this stuff in a single method

They contain the same fields:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class DeleteDeveloperResponse extends DeveloperResponseBaseEntity<DeleteDeveloperResponse >{
   private long id;
   private BigDecimal salary;
   private String message;
}
```

I created a basic class, but I don't know how to connect them correctly:

```
@Getter
@Setter
public abstract class DeveloperResponseBaseEntity<T> {
   private long id;
   private BigDecimal salary;
   private String message;
}
```

Here is my method, this should look like:

```
public <T extends > T getDeveloperResponseFromDeveloper(Developer developer) {
    T response = new T(); //but we can't create object of Generic 
    // OR T response = new DeveloperResponseBaseEntity<T>;
    response.setId(developer.getd());
    //other set operations
    return response;
}
```

And I want to invoke this method with different classes, for example:

```
AddDeveloperResponse addDevResponse = userMapper.getDeveloperResponseFromDeveloper(Developer);
EditDeveloperResponse editDevResponse = userMapper.getDeveloperResponseFromDeveloper(Developer);
//OR
EditDeveloperResponse editDevResponse = userMapper.<EditDeveloperResponse>getDeveloperResponseFromDeveloper(Developer);
```

If you can, just explain to me how it should work generally in java

If you know related topics, send them in comments, I will be grateful for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could maybe use something like this:

```java
public <T extends DeveloperResponseBaseEntity<T>> T getDeveloperResponseFromDeveloper(Developer developer, Supplier<? extends T> responseConstructor) {
    T response = responseConstructor.get();
    response.setId(developer.getId());
    // other set operations
    return response;
}
```

And then call it like this, assuming `AddDeveloperResponse` has a no arg constructor:

```java
AddDeveloperResponse addDevResponse = userMapper.getDeveloperResponseFromDeveloper(Developer, AddDeveloperResponse::new);
```

As you probably know, you can't instantiate a generic type directly, so you need to help java a bit. I did this with `Supplier<? extends T> responseConstructor` where you can pass the constructor of the type you want to instantiate. You could also pass an instance directly, i.e. replace the `Supplier responseConstructor` with `T response` directly.

Comment: But i cant invoke method setId, when i do

response.setId(user.getId());

I get compilation error 'cannot find symbol method setId'

Comment: @Rostyslav you *should* be able to, because `DeveloperResponseBaseEntity` has getters and setters, and `T response` will have at least access to the methods defined by `DeveloperResponseBaseEntity`